# Why can't I use a single "Cells" reference as a "Range" parameter

Tags: vba, excel

This question: [Copy from one workbook to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33021744/copy-from-one-workbook-to-another/33022198#33022198) made me realize that while I knew how to fix the issue described, I didn't know why it caused an error.

`Range("A1").Select` is fine.

`Range(Cells(1,1),Cells(1,1)).Select` is fine.

`Range(Cells(1,1).Address).Select` is fine.

`Range(Cells(1,1)).Select` returns an **Application defined or Object defined error**

Is this a bug, or is there a deeper reason that I don't understand?

Comment: If you only want the single cell, the `Range` is not needed.  You would simply call `Cell(1,1).select` no range needed.  This is not a bug but a redundant call and therefore not needed.  Look at @ExcelHero answer in the question you referenced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand a little:

> Range("A1").Select is fine.

Pretty straightforward as to why.

> Range(Cells(1,1),Cells(1,1)).Select is fine.

Yes, this ends up being equivalent to `Range(A1:A1)`

> Range(Cells(1,1).Address).Select is fine.

This ends up being equivalent to `Range("$A$1")`  This is because the `.Address` part resolves to the cell's address.

> Range(Cells(1,1)).Select returns an Application defined or Object defined error

The error is because VB tried to resolve this but can't, since it's just a single cell (and a `Range` is multiple cells (or at least the same cell listed twice, as the second example above)).  But, unlike the third example, there's nothing telling VBA to use `Cells(1,1)`'s address, this is just a reference to the cell in general...therefore, VB doesn't know what to do with it really...do you want the `Cells(1,1).Font`, or the `.Value`, or the `.Row`, etc...

I hope that helps a little, but check out the link @Soulfire provided, and you can Google around for more details on `Range()` if it's still unclear.

Comment: Not to pick nits but `Range(Cells(1,1).Address)` actually resolves to `Range("$A$1")` since the *RowAbsolute* and *ColumnAbsolute* parameters of the [Range.Address property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837625.aspx) default to `True`.

Comment: @Jeeped - No nits picked, you're exactly right. I just forgot that it gets the absolute reference (I'll update my post).  Thanks for the additional info!

Answer (score 2):

Cells(1,1) evaluates to the value of what is located in that cell.

It is equivalent to Cells(1,1).Value

You would have the same issue with Range(Range("A1")).Select

Comment: This [article](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DefaultMember.aspx) expands on this point a bit.  Each class has a default member, and the default member for cells is `.Value`.